# Partial derivatives need help?

Tags: derivatives

I have to find the derivative $dw$ if $w=F(u,v,z)$ where $u=x^2+y^2, v=x^2-y^2$ and $z=2xy$.
So $dw=\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}dz + \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial w}{\partial v}dv$. How to find $dw$ now?

Comment: **HINT** Apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

$dw$ is called a differential.  It measures the tendency for the dependent variable $w$ to change as the independent variables $x$ and $y$ change.  To compute $dw$, we use your formula, along with the differentials $du$, $dv$, and $dz$ (computed the same way you suggest).
$$du=2xdx+2ydy\\dv=2xdx-2ydy\\dz=2ydx+2xdy$$

Next, using your formula, we see that
$$\begin{align}dw&=\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}(2xdx+2ydy)+\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}(2xdx-2ydy)+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}(2ydx+2xdy)\\&=(2x\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}+2x\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}+2y\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})dx+(2y\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}-2y\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}+2x\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})dy\end{align}$$

Without knowing an explicitly formula for $w=F(u,v,z)$, this is as explicit as we can be.